# Sum for every case of a value in column

Tags: matlab, unique, cumulative-sum

A sample of my matrix is given below:

```
[ 1  43; 
  1  15;
  1  34;   
  5  15;
  5  32;
  7   2;
  7  43;
  7  16;
  7  75 ]
```

I want the sum of column 2 for each unique value in column 1. So, it would be:

```
[ 1   92;    
  5   47;    
  7  136 ]
```

It would be possible with a `for`-loop, but it would be very time consuming. So I am looking for a faster solution.

Comment: Shouldn't that `134` be `136` instead?

Comment: you're right. Edited it, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
[C,~,ic] = unique(A(:,1));
result = [C, accumarray(ic,A(:,2))];
```

Also, you can find [unique](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) and [accumarray](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) in the standard documentation.